# How to remove area of interest from the background of an image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm starting to work with image processing in pattern recognition, and I need to identify the colors of fur spots. With this, I need to remove possible noises from these images, such as hairs, and then work on only the skin spot in order to identify their colors. As a result, plot the colors in a 3D chart.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example? ([I downvoted because there is no code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/))* / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Comment: And it is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: Ok @Hille, Can you help me with this issue?

Comment: Nope i can't really help you with your specific question - i can only help you to create a good question so it will attract more user who could help you out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first I would change the color space of the image so I could perform some sort of threshold on the image to prepare it for further processing. In the example I tried it by converting to gray color space and with OTSU threshold and the result was good.

Result with blur+OTSU:

[image]

But note that if you want to automate such a process then you would need to try different methods of tranformation since I assume the color of the pigmentation varies. For the begining have a look at HSV, GRAY, HLS colorspaces and BINARY, OTSU, ADAPTIVE MEAN thresholds. The key in this step is to make your region of interest united and seperated from other noises. Once you have this figured out you can begin searching for contours. In this case the mole is the biggest contour but you should note that if there were other noises that were bigger than this mole, selecting the biggest one will not work. You would have to make other criteria to differ your observated contour (for example its shape, height and width ratio etc.). Once you have selected your observed contour draw it on a new blank mask and the perform some arithmetic operation like the `cv2.bitwise_and()` and you will get the result. Hope it gives you a kick in the right direction. Cheers!

Example code:

```
#Import all necessery libraries
import numpy as np
import cv2

#Read the image and perform threshold
img = cv2.imread('mole.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(5,5),0)
_,thresh = cv2.threshold(blur,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

#Search for contours and select the biggest one
_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cnt = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

#Create a new mask for the result image
h, w = img.shape[:2]
mask = np.zeros((h, w), np.uint8)

#Draw the contour on the new mask and perform the bitwise operation
cv2.drawContours(mask, [cnt],-1, 255, -1)
res = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)

#Display the result
cv2.imwrite('mole_res.jpg', res)
cv2.imshow('img', res)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: glad I could help!